# How to build datamatrix scanner for android?

Tags: android

I want to develop an app for scanning 2D Datamatrix code in android, i have searched a lot but did not find anything , so please help me in building one scanner to scan datamatrix code.

P.S. Zxing is not scanning datamatrix code.

Answer (score 0):

zxing is scanning 2D datamatrix code :-),
 when i tested they were fake datamatrix codes.
Thanx anyways